# Is it fair to do this?

Tags: visual, rebus

The following rebus regards something commonly done, in certain places; it's debatable as to whether or not this is a fair practice.

[image: Image 1]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My guess:

> Grading on a bell curve

It may not be fair because

> It doesn't matter how well you do in the course, only how well you do compared to the other students in your class. If you're in a class with a bunch of underachievers, it would be easy to get a top score and thus a passing grade. Meanwhile, your friend might have class amongst the smarties and do just as well as you, but receive a lower grade.

Comment: This is correct!  I give you 100%, and the other two answers get a 90%.  *snicker*

Comment: Never would have got this but fits perfectly! Well done

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb, but how did you get `grading` from `systematization`? o_O

Comment: Grading is really a more narrow definition for "sorting".

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> **Over ordering**

Because:

> **systematization** = making a system/**order** and 
>  **tintinnabulation** = chime/**ring**. There is a line separating them like a fraction with order over ring...over ordering.

Something commonly done, in certain places; it's debatable as to whether or not this is a fair practice.

> People often take other out to dinner and offer to pay for their tab. It is polite to not order too much as it will become expensive. However, some people will take advantage of the free meal and overorder. It's debatable if it's fair because the person *did* offer to pay in the first place.

Comment: Nice try, but don't forget to take into account the shape of tintinnabulation.  Get the second half and it might make it easier to get the first.

Answer (score 2):

My lame guess is:

> Ordering around

Because:

> systematisation (creating a system / creating order) + Tintinnabulation (ringing sound),  which is then made round. So... Order ring around.

Comment: Good try, but you're on the right track.